# Could not initialize class persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$ in sbt yet test works in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: spring, scala, neo4j, sbt, specs2

I wanted to see if all my test are passing after `git merge`, and noticed that `sbt test` failed. All of those tests are the ones that are using Spring context.

As to not load Spring context for every test I created the following trait:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

trait Neo4jSpringContext {
  val context = Neo4jSpringContext.context
}

object Neo4jSpringContext {
  val context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testNeo4jApplicationContext.xml")
}
```

and in my tests I am using it as follows:

```
class CreateRetrieveAirplaneAndLegsSpec extends Specification with Neo4jSpringContext with NoTimeConversions
```

Now, in the logs I can see that the context is being set up (logging information) but then I am facing the error:

```
[error] Could not create an instance of persistence.list.neo4j.CreateRetrieveAirplaneAndLegsSpec
[error]   caused by java.lang.Exception: Could not instantiate class persistence.list.neo4j.Neo4jDuplicateFlightDesignatorCheckSpec: Could not initialize class persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.liftedTree1$1(Classes.scala:104)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:93)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:213)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:118)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:118)
[error]   scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationEither(BaseSpecification.scala:118)
[error]   org.specs2.runner.TestInterfaceRunner.runSpecification(TestInterfaceRunner.scala:59)
[error]   org.specs2.runner.TestInterfaceRunner.run(TestInterfaceRunner.scala:54)
[error]   sbt.RunnerWrapper$1.runRunner(FrameworkWrapper.java:200)
[error]   sbt.RunnerWrapper$1.execute(FrameworkWrapper.java:236)
[error]   sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:84)
[error]   sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:94)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:212)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:229)
[error]   sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:211)
[error]   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
[error]   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
[error]   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
[error]   sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[error]   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error]   caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$
[error]   persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$class.$init$(Neo4jSpringContext.scala:6)
[error]   persistence.list.neo4j.Neo4jDuplicateFlightDesignatorCheckSpec.<init>(Neo4jDuplicateFlightDesignatorCheckSpec.scala:12)
[error]   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[error]   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.createInstanceFor(Classes.scala:157)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.createInstanceFor(Classes.scala:213)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$createInstanceOfEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:147)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$createInstanceOfEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:147)
[error]   scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.createInstanceOfEither(Classes.scala:147)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.createInstanceOfEither(Classes.scala:213)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.org$specs2$reflect$Classes$$createInstanceForConstructor(Classes.scala:120)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$5.apply(Classes.scala:98)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$5.apply(Classes.scala:98)
[error]   scala.collection.GenSeqViewLike$Mapped$class.apply(GenSeqViewLike.scala:48)
[error]   scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$3.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:78)
[error]   scala.collection.GenSeqViewLike$Filtered$class.apply(GenSeqViewLike.scala:91)
[error]   scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:80)
[error]   scala.collection.GenSeqViewLike$Mapped$class.apply(GenSeqViewLike.scala:48)
[error]   scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$3.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:78)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.liftedTree1$1(Classes.scala:103)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:93)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:213)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:118)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:118)
[error]   scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationEither(BaseSpecification.scala:118)
[error]   org.specs2.runner.TestInterfaceRunner.runSpecification(TestInterfaceRunner.scala:59)
[error]   org.specs2.runner.TestInterfaceRunner.run(TestInterfaceRunner.scala:54)
[error]   sbt.RunnerWrapper$1.runRunner(FrameworkWrapper.java:200)
[error]   sbt.RunnerWrapper$1.execute(FrameworkWrapper.java:236)
[error]   sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:84)
[error]   sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:94)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:212)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:229)
[error]   sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:211)
[error]   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
[error]   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
[error]   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
[error]   sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[error]   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I was first thinking that there may be some problem because of parallel execution of tests in sbt, but `parallelExecution in Test := false` didn't help -- the tests keep failing.

Interestingly, if I execute the tests in IntelliJ IDEA everything works and hence face no errors.

EDIT:

```
name := """scheduling-backend"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

resolvers += "spray nightlies" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

resolvers += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"

resolvers += "Neo4j Cypher DSL Repository" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.0" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.0",
  "io.spray" % "spray-can" % "1.3.0",
  "io.spray" % "spray-routing" % "1.3.0",
  "io.spray" % "spray-testkit" % "1.3.0" % "test",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.2.5",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.7" % "test->default",
  "org.springframework.scala" % "spring-scala" % "1.0.0.M2",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "3.0.0.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "3.0.0.RELEASE",
  "javax.validation" % "validation-api" % "1.1.0.Final",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.8.0",
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "2.0.1" % "test" classifier "tests",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-language:_",
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8"
)

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

Comment: I suggest that you try changing your vals to lazy vals to see if that improves things.

Comment: @Eric that doesn't explain why it works in IDEA, does it? Interesting issue.

Comment: @Andna could that issue be due to missing dependencies that are defined outside sbt -- in IDEA only? Can you reimport the sbt project again?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I can try to reimport the project but there are no unmanaged dependencies in my project. I can post my `build.sbt` in my original post.

Comment: Why do you have JUnit and Specs2 in a single project? Can you include the entire sbt shell session up to the error to the post? And the line `"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "2.0.1" % "test" classifier "tests"` caught my attention yet I can't explain why :-) I've seen `classifier` used very sparingly.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski indeed there might be a class init issue depending on the classpath order. I was just expecting that a lazy val would make that clearer (maybe with another exception).

Comment: Ah, right. I'm still on my way to understand Scala so pardon my comment.

Comment: No worries, I'm mostly shooting in the dark here :-)

Comment: About the classifier:

I remembered why I added this classifier. Normal `Neo4j-kernel` does not have `ImpermamentDatabase` which I use for testing. `http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html` (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html)

Comment: Can you execute `sbt test:console` and then `Neo4jSpringContext.context` inside? I'm pretty sure that's something wrong with the `object Neo4jSpringContext` as the message `Could not initialize class persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$` says.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I had to completely remove my first version of the answer as it turned out completely off base.

The following **build.sbt** worked fine:

```
name := "neo4j"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

// unresolved dependency: org.neo4j#neo4j-cypher-dsl;2.0.1: not found otherwise
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "spring" at "http://repo.spring.io/release",
  "neo4j-releases" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "2.1.0-M01" % "test" classifier "tests",
  // https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/releases
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11-RC1" % "test",
  "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-all" % "1.3" % "test",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "3.0.1.RELEASE" % "test",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "4.0.2.RELEASE" % "test"
)

// http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#options
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

It worked fine with [the following unit test](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j/neo4j/2.0.1/community/embedded-examples/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples/Neo4jBasicDocTest.java) described in http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html (as pointed out in @Andna's comment).

```
/**
 * Licensed to Neo Technology under one or more contributor
 * license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright
 * ownership. Neo Technology licenses this file to you under
 * the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
package org.neo4j.examples;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory;

/**
 * An example of unit testing with Neo4j.
 */
public class Neo4jBasicDocTest
{
    protected GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    /**
     * Create temporary database for each unit test.
     */
    // START SNIPPET: beforeTest
    @Before
    public void prepareTestDatabase()
    {
        graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    }
    // END SNIPPET: beforeTest

    /**
     * Shutdown the database.
     */
    // START SNIPPET: afterTest
    @After
    public void destroyTestDatabase()
    {
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }
    // END SNIPPET: afterTest

    @Test
    public void startWithConfiguration()
    {
        // START SNIPPET: startDbWithConfig
        GraphDatabaseService db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder()
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.nodestore_mapped_memory_size, "10M" )
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.string_block_size, "60" )
            .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.array_block_size, "300" )
            .newGraphDatabase();
        // END SNIPPET: startDbWithConfig
        db.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateNode()
    {
        // START SNIPPET: unitTest
        Node n = null;
        try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            n = graphDb.createNode();
            n.setProperty( "name", "Nancy" );
            tx.success();
        }

        // The node should have a valid id
        assertThat( n.getId(), is( greaterThan( -1L ) ) );

        // Retrieve a node by using the id of the created node. The id's and
        // property should match.
        try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            Node foundNode = graphDb.getNodeById( n.getId() );
            assertThat( foundNode.getId(), is( n.getId() ) );
            assertThat( (String) foundNode.getProperty( "name" ), is( "Nancy" ) );
        }
        // END SNIPPET: unitTest
    }
}
```

I'm experimenting...

Comment: I remembered why I added this classifier. Normal `Neo4j-kernel` does not have `ImpermamentDatabase` which I use for testing. `http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html` (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html)

Comment: You were right -- the `classifier` was required as were the other things I'd thought unnecessary. I then need more data to sort it out. A new comment in the original post

Comment: I am posting new question on SO regarding my problem, I discovered that it is not an issue with `Specs2` but probably something with `spring-data-neo4j`. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598124/spring-data-neo4j-automatic-repository-generation-and-scala-classes