# Spring data neo4j - automatic repository generation and scala classes

Tags: spring, scala, sbt

My question is partially connected to [Could not initialize class persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$ in sbt yet test works in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511382/could-not-initialize-class-persistence-common-neo4j-neo4jspringcontext-in-sbt-y)

I created simple trait to decorate my test classes with `Spring` context and to achieve context caching:

```
package persistence.common.neo4j

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

trait Neo4jSpringContext {
  val context = Neo4jSpringContext.context
}
object Neo4jSpringContext {
  val context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testNeo4jApplicationContext.xml")
}
```

Now when I executed the tests using `IDEA` I did not observe any problems but when I tried to execute them through `SBT` I got strange errors saying that there were problems like `Could not initialize class persistence.common.neo4j.Neo4jSpringContext$`. I firstly thought that it was some problem with `Specs2` framework (which I am using to write tests) but today I did some more digging.

I discovered that after I comment out the line:

```
<neo4j:repositories base-package="persistence"/>
```

which results in automatic generation of repository classes, `Neo4jSpringContext` class is loaded correctly.

Now this got me thinking, may this be caused by trying to use automatic mapping feature with scala classes?

To test this theory I created very simple class that can be run from command line:

```
package persistence

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

object Test extends App {
  val c = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("neo4jApplicationContext.xml")
}
```

and my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!--<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" index="0"/>
    </bean>
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
    -->
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="test/graph2.db"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="persistence"/>

<!--    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromDateTimeToLongConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromLongToDateTimeConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromPeriodToIntegerConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromIntegerToPeriodConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromCarrierToStringConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromStringToCarrierConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromFlightNumberToIntegerConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromIntegerToFlightNumberConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromOptionalSuffixToStringConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromStringToOptionalSuffixConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromLocalDateToLongConverter"/>
                <bean class="persistence.common.neo4j.converter.FromLongToLocalDateConverter"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>-->

</beans>
```

As you can see I commented out everything I could and just initialize database and repositories.

When I try to run this class from `IDEA`: everything is ok. When I try to run it from SBT i get very lengthy stack trace. I posted it here because it has about 1k lines: http://pastebin.com/U0rTyERZ.

I think the most interesting part is the one at the bottom:

```
[error] (run-main) org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/path/to/project/target/scala-2.10/classes/persistence/Test$delayedInit$body.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/runtime/AbstractFunction0.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[error] Offending resource: class path resource [neo4jApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/path/to/project/target/scala-2.10/classes/persistence/Test$delayedInit$body.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/runtime/AbstractFunction0.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/path/to/project/target/scala-2.10/classes/persistence/Test$delayedInit$body.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/runtime/AbstractFunction0.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Offending resource: class path resource [neo4jApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/path/to/project/target/scala-2.10/classes/persistence/Test$delayedInit$body.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/runtime/AbstractFunction0.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.handleError(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at persistence.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at persistence.Test$.main(Test.scala:5)
    at persistence.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/path/to/project/target/scala-2.10/classes/persistence/Test$delayedInit$body.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/runtime/AbstractFunction0.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(RepositoryComponentProvider.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at persistence.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at persistence.Test$.main(Test.scala:5)
    at persistence.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/runtime/AbstractFunction0.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(RepositoryComponentProvider.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at persistence.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at persistence.Test$.main(Test.scala:5)
    at persistence.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

which says that some `scala` class can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

When I specified more concrete package for scanning (the one that only contained repository interfaces) everything started to work ok. I still don't know why tests could run from `IDEA` but at least I found out an easy way around my problem.